# Code generation from restricted set of input

Tags: metaprogramming, code-generation

Suppose I have a mapping (with known types) such as

1: false,
4: false,
8: true,
16: true

And I want to generate a function take input and gives the correct output. I don't care what happens for any input that is not in the above mapping, for example 3 will never be expected.

A naive solution would be to generate the function with a switch statement, for instance

```
f(int x) {
    if x == 1 return false;
    else if x == 4 return false;
    else if x == 8 return true;
    else if x == 16 return true;
}
```

I want to be able to generate code that doesn't scale in memory with the set of input.

```
f(int x) {
    return x >= 8;
}
```

Does this problem have a name? What area should I research into?

Answer (score 0):

You want to "guess" what code to generate for the inputs not provided.

**You can't do it.**

[EDIT: On further discussion, it is now clear to me that he doesn't care about such inputs.  I'm leaving the answer as is, because people will assume, as I did, that he must care.  Surprising advice offered at end of this answer, anyway].

Imagine you have an adversary that is going to specify a function f on all inputs, but s/he only provides you a sample, asin your example. some fixed set of inputs.   You now apply an oracle, that guesses that f(9) is *true*.   Your adversary promptly shows that her function has f(9) is actually *false*.   Likewise if you guess f(9) is false.

The adversary can always manufacture an input/output pair that does not match what your code generator guesses.   So you simply cannot get it right.

What you can do is to accept that your guesses may be wrong, and try to choose a function that has the least complexity that explains the input/output pairs you have seen so far.  Your example is essentially one of these.

If you believe that "simple" functions are a better approximation of the world than complex ones, you can generate code and hope you don't encounter an adversary in nature.

Don't count on it to be reliable.

With those caveats, OP might be interested in the [GNU SuperOptimizer](https://github.com/bonzini/superopt).  This finds short sequences of machine instructions that produce a provided set of input/output pairs [actually, I think you give it function that computes the answer, like OP's original function] by the "obviously" crazy idea of literally trying every instruction sequence.

The genius behind the superoptimizer is that this stunt actually works in practice for short instruction sequences.

I think it would be easy to modify it to produce generic "C" instructions (e.g. valid C actions) since I believe it uses C actions to model machine instructions anyway.  You would probably have to modify your function to produce "don't care" results for inputs that don't matter, and teach GNU superoptimizer that "don't care" is a valid result.   That would in fact be a useful addition to the GNU superoptimizer for its original purpose, too.

Comment: I'm not going to have any input other than the set of input provided. I'm not sure what to research to generate code, most of what I can find relates to changing variables in templates or spottiing a pattern and implementing it yourself

Comment: So how do you account for the fact that your generated f will produce answers for more inputs than you are provided as a specification?

Comment: So how do you account for the fact that your generated f will produce answers for more inputs than you provided as a specification?   Do you care?

Comment: Nope, I only care about the inout I have provided. It is easy for a human to figure out a pattern and extend it to other input, whereas I want to "optmise" for only the provided input

Comment: "extend it to other input"  Presumably, you mean "in a way that computes the intended value".   OK, my point is that you cannot do this "right".

Comment: Sure, I'll agree with you that there is no definition of right. Like the Ayrshire you can draw an inifinite amount of lines through the same two points. But I only careally about those points, and not the shape of the curve or even if it is continuous

Comment: See revised answer, esp new last paragraphs on Gnu Superoptimizer.